# MS Access Force report footer to bottom of page

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a report for a proposal. I would like to keep a professional look and always force the terms section to the bottom of the page. I could use the page footer but I only want the terms to show on the last page.

My idea is somehow with VBA to set the height of a dummy group such that it forces the report footer to the bottom. The problem is that you can't explicitly set the height of a section.

Anyone else out there with another idea (That works)? :-)

Thanks, Jeff

Comment: I don't quite see how having the terms at the bottom of the last page gives the report a "professional look".

Comment: It doesn't necessarily, but it (in my opinion) doesn't look professional to have the signature section on the bottom of every page. If you are using pre-printed forms you don't have any options so people are kind of used to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Me.PageFooterSection.Visible = (Me.txtPage <> Me.txtPages)
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The negative to this trick is your footer has to be expanded and eats up space for your details section. I found another solution and documented it in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134640/685

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:
http://bytes.com/topic/misc/answers/499733-report-footer-location-problem#post1939746

To accomodate single page reports you could do something like

```
If Me.Pages > 0 Then
Me.Section(4).Visible = (iif(Me.Pages = 1, True, Me.Page = Me.Pages))
EndIf
```

Note that Access only calculates the number of pages if you have page numbers on your report.  If you don't want them displayed you can set their Visible property to False.